# What is the term for the same ROCAUC performance between groups but different sensitivity at the same operating threshold?

Tags: concept-drift, data-drift

I have a model that predicts disease in Group A with a ROCAUC of 0.90.
That same model also predicts disease in Group B with a ROCAUC of 0.90.

However, at an operating threshold of 0.5, the sensitivity/specificity differs dramatically between the two groups. Groups A and B are identical in regards to age distribution and sex.

What is this problem called? Is this a form of dataset shift? I'd like to read more about how to deal with this scenario.